# Quebrar string com múltiplos símbolos

Tags: c

Eu tenho uma string no seguinte formato:

> 0:nome:senha:email:etc

Preciso separá-la em cada ':', e estou fazendo isso com a função strtok(string, ':').

O problema é que a senha pode ser nula, e o padrão fica assim:

> 0:nome::email:etc

E aí a strtok não funciona mais, porque ela não tira só o primeiro ':', mas os dois.

Tem alguma maneira de contornar isso usando a strtok, ou até mesmo fazer esse processo de um jeito mais inteligente?

Obrigado.

Comment: O que tu quer que apareça caso a senha ou qualquer outra opção for nula ?

Comment: Nada, uma string vazia. O problema é que a função pega o e-mail (no exemplo) e aí bagunça o resto do código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infelizmente, a função `strtok()` não é capaz de interpretar dois *tokens* seguidos como um campo "nulo".

Uma solução seria implementar uma outra versão de de `strtok()` que seja capaz de se comportar exatamente igual, porém capaz de interpretar *tokens* seguidos.

Segue uma solução baseada na função `strpbrk()`:

```
#include <string.h>

char * strtok2( char * str, char const * delim )
{
    static char * src = NULL;
    char * p = NULL;
    char * ret = NULL;

    if(str)
        src = str;

    if(!src)
        return NULL;

    p = strpbrk( src, delim );

    if(p)
    {
        *p = 0;
        ret = src;
        src = ++p;
    }
    else if(*src)
    {
        ret = src;
        src = NULL;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Testando:

```
int main( void )
{
    int i = 0;
    char str[] = "0:nome::email:etc";

    char * p = strtok2( str, ":" );

    while(p)
    {
        printf ("%d: %s\n", ++i, *p ? p : "[vazio]");

        p = strtok2( NULL, ":" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
1: 0
2: nome
3: [vazio]
4: email
5: etc
```

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado.

Comment: Qual é a necessidade disso ?  p = strtok2( NULL, ":" );

Comment: @YODA: Retornar o ponteiro para o dado após o *próximo* token.